# accessing local fonts requires system reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, brackets

I'm using Brackets 1.13 and Ubuntu 18.04.

When I download a font and install it locally, it requires a full system reboot before I see the font applied in my Brackets live preview.

Anybody know the technical side behind linux / Ubuntu fonts and specifically, how can I get fonts available immediately, not requiring a full system restart?

Thanks ~~

Comment: Using the Gnome Font Manager, I've noticed the same issue on occasion. See if logging out as user and logging in again helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion ... sounds like a plan.